# Javascript stop PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a button **Delete File** in `script1.php`.

After clicking on that button, I wan to display a JS `confirm` box to confirm the action.

I'm using this code :

```
<script language="javascript">
    if (confirm("Are you sure to delete this file ?")) {
        // Will continue executing the script
    } else {
        window.stop();
    }
</script>
<?php
// Delete the file ...
?>
```

This code does what I want : The `php` won't execute unless the user confirms the action.

**Now**, if I want to customize the `confirm box` (Add another button, modify the style ...), I thought of using `jQuery .dialog`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Do you wanna continue ?">
  <p>Are you sure to delete this file ?</p>
</div>

<script language="javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: "auto",
    width: 400,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Do it": function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      },
      Cancel: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
        window.stop();
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>
<?php
// Delete the file ...
?>
```

Unfortunately, this does not work, and the rest of the php code will be executed any way.

So, is there a way to "halt" the execution til the click on the "Do it" button?

Comment: That PHP code will run regardless of whatever happens in JavaScript. The whole page is rendered *completely* before the HTML is sent to the client. The client receives the JavaScript and can decide if it wants to run it or not.

Comment: In order to have a JavaScript action initiate something in PHP you must either redirect or make an AJAX call. There is no other way.

Comment: It feels like you have a misunderstanding about what runs server side and what runs client side.

Comment: Well, I'm feeling stupid after reading what you have said!
AJAX it's then.

Comment: In addition to @sjahan's point I'd suggest reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13840429/519413) as a grounder on the differences between client and server code.

Comment: Thank you @RoryMcCrossan, I have a good understanding about that. Just maybe this  is what happens after 8 hours of work !
I'll figure this out, and i'll post an answer here for future viewers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate front- and backend, send messages between two.

Javascript asks for confirmation and if gets it - sends a request to php script.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Do you wanna continue ?">
  <p>Are you sure to delete this file ?</p>
</div>

<script language="javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: "auto",
    width: 400,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Do it": function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
        $.post( "post.php", {filename: "error"})
            .done(function( data ) {
                alert('Success: '+JSON.stringify(data));
            })
            .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('ERROR: '+JSON.stringify(errorThrown));
            });
  },
      },
      Cancel: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
        window.stop();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

php script waits for a filename, deals with file manipulation (e.g. deleting) and sends some feedback.

```
<?php
$fn = $_POST['filename'];
//delete file with name $fn
//send result
if($result=='error') //something went wrong
{
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Ended up with bad result');
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $response_array['status'] = "error"; 
    $response_array['data'] = $data;   
}else{ //everything ok
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $response_array['status'] = 'success'; 
    $response_array['data'] = $data;
}   
echo json_encode($response_array);
?>
```